# Passing Ionic checkbox values to Firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I got a problem while updating my Ionic checkbox values to Firebase.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Problemfeld 1</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox  checked="false" [(ngModel)]="problemfeld1" name="problemfeld1"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Problemfeld 2</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox  checked="false" [(ngModel)]="problemfeld2" name="problemfeld2"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Problemfeld 3</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox  checked="false" [(ngModel)]="problemfeld3" name="problemfeld3"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Problemfeld 4</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox  checked="false" [(ngModel)]="problemfeld4" name="problemfeld4"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>  
</ion-list>

<button ion-button (click)="updateProblemfeld()" [navPush]="problemdefinitionPage">Weiter</button>
```

This is the function in my Ionic Page:

```
updateProblemfeld(problemfeld1, problemfeld2,problemfeld3,problemfeld4) {
      this.szenarioProvider.updateProblemfeld(problemfeld1,  problemfeld2, problemfeld3, problemfeld4);
  }
```

And this is how I pass it to Firebase:

```
updateProblemfeld(problemfeld1: boolean, problemfeld2: boolean, problemfeld3: boolean, problemfeld4: boolean): firebase.Promise<any> {  
  return firebase.database().ref('/szenarioData')
  .child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
  .child('problemfeld').update({
    problemfeld1: problemfeld1,
      problemfeld2: problemfeld2,
      problemfeld3: problemfeld3,
      problemfeld4: problemfeld4,
    });
  }
```

And this is what the Error looks like:

`Firebase.update failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'szenarioData.hR4feTPka8fuMDGK3YV0nFrDs1A3.problemfeld.problemfeld1'`

Can you think of a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My god,
I looked for a solution for 2 days till I decided to ask this question.
And 30 minutes after asking I found it:

Button in the HTML document needs to be like this:

```html
<button ion-button (click)="updateProblemfeld(problemfeld1, problemfeld2, problemfeld3, problemfeld4)" [navPush]="problemdefinitionPage">Weiter</button>
```

I simply forgot to pass the values...